# Задача по объединению нескольких .xlsx файлов в один в Python с помощью библиотеки openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Задача следующая: Главный бухгалтер компании "Рога и копыта" случайно удалил ведомость с начисленной зарплатой. К счастью, у него сохранились расчётные листки всех сотрудников. Помогите по этим расчётным листкам восстановить зарплатную ведомость. Архив с расчётными листками доступен по ссылке https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kg1CZ-ynVyElcYslOjOe0gGbBgFJz9Xr?usp=sharing

Ведомость должна содержать 1000 строк, в каждой строке должно быть указано ФИО сотрудника и, через пробел, его зарплата. Сотрудники должны быть упорядочены по алфавиту.

Я прекрасно вижу, что надо из каждого файла извлечь ячейки B2, D2 и объединить их в словарь или в отдельный .xlsx файл. Но я никак не могу найти инструкции в Интернет, как это сделать с помощью библиотеки openpyxl. Даже в официальной документации к этой библиотеке этого нет.
Написание остального кода, я полагаю, не будет представлять для меня трудностей. Но вот объединение данных из файлов..... Кто знает, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: __Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.__ Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и __укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности__ при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Если бы я нашла приемлемое решение через openpyxl, я бы с удовольствием написала код.  Поэтому и задала вопрос без кода. Если Вы заметили, я не прошу писать мне что-то готовое. Просто попросила подсказать способ объединения файлов с помощью библиотеки openpyxl в один. Если Вы видите в этом что-то, противоречащее правилам, можете подать жалобу или заблокировать вопрос.

Comment: Образовательный ресурс, на котором я прохожу обучение, дал информацию только по openpyxl, а потом разместил эту задачу. Делаю вывод - ее можно решить через эту библиотеку. Но решения не нахожу. Если у Вас есть ссылка на ресурс, поделитесь, пожалуйста. Мне достаточно. Коды за меня писать не прошу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Алгоритм решения на чистом Openpyxl:

1. В цикле читаете две ячейки (B2 и D2) данных средствами Openpyxl из каждого файла в список списков - в каждом элементе внешнего списка будет два элемента - ФИО и сумма начисления.
2. Создаете Pandas DataFrame из собранного списка списков
3. Записываете получившийся на шаге 2. DataFrame в Excel файл. [Ссылка на документацию по Openpyxl по работе с Pandas.](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html) В качестве альтернативы использованию Pandas, можно записывать собранные данные средствами Openpyxl вложенными циклами "по одной ячейке".

Comment: Спасибо большое за алгоритм и документацию. Завтра все изучу и попытаюсь реализовать.

Comment: @Irina, если вы приведете в вопросе собственные (пусть и неудачные) попытки решения, то наверняка получите в качестве ответа готовый и проверенный код. ;) По правилам ресурса, здесь более активно помогают тем, кто прилагает усилия и сам пытается решить задачу/проблему...

Comment: Я обязательно приведу код данной задачи после ее решения. Сама отвечу на свой вопрос. Это нужно, в первую очередь, мне. До этой задачи все мои вопросы сопровождались кодом.  Мне не нужен готовый и проверенный код от кого-то. Я хочу создать его сама. Не всегда выходит. Поверьте мне, я прилагаю усилия и не пытаюсь выезэжать за счет чьих-либо знаний и навыков. Вам большое спасибо за ссылку на документацию. Это то, что мне было нужно. Удачи.

Comment: Код написала. Привела в качестве ответа на собственный вопрос. Изящного однострочного решения не получилось. Но мне простительно. Я новичок. Как и хотела, удалось обойтись без pandas. Pandas - крутая вещь, но я хотела использовать только то, что мне предоставил образовательный ресурс. Вроде, получилось.

Comment: @Irina, вы молодец, так держать! :)

Answer (score 2):

Приведу алгоритм решения вместо самого решения, т.к. в вопросе отсутствует попытка собственного решения.

1. воспользуйтесь функцией `glob.glob()` или `pathlib.glob()` для того, чтобы прочитать все Execl файлы в список Pandas DataFrame.
2. для каждого файла из списка, полученного в предыдущем шаге прочитайте Excel файл в Pandas DataFrame, пропустив ненужные строки и столбцы, воспользовавшись  параметрами `skiprows`, `usecols` и `header`.
3. объедините все получившиеся в предыдущем шаге DataFrame'ы в один, воспользовавшись методом `pd.concat()`.

PS при желании, получится однострочное решение...

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я нашла много решений этой задачи через pandas. Ваше решение тоже реализую. Мне интересно найти решение через openpyxl. Именно поэтому я не смогла написать код. Спасибо еще раз

Comment: @Irina, решение на "чистом" openpyxl будет громоздким и неэффективным и будет включать в себя вложенные циклы.

Comment: Спасибо. Не понимаю тогда, почему в образовательном курсе учат одному, а задачи дают на другое. Это ни в коем случае не в Вашу сторону комментарии. Это риторическое восклицание. Вам спасибо большое за участие. Решу через pandas.

Answer (score 1):

Изящного однострочного кода не получилось. Ну уж что получилось. Как и хотела, без pandas. Но пришлось использовать glob.
Привожу код. Тестирующая система приняла ответ. Вывод ответа сделала на консоль.

```
import glob
import openpyxl

vedomost = {}

path = "C:\\Users\\Asus\\OneDrive\Masaüstü\\RogaiKopita"
file_identifier = "*.xlsx"

for f in glob.glob(path + "/*" + file_identifier):
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)
    sh = wb.active
    b = sh['B2'].value
    d = sh['D2'].value
    vedomost[b] = d
vedomost1 = sorted(vedomost.items())
for i in vedomost1:
    print(i[0], i[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import openpyxl
vedomost = []
for i in range(1,1001):
    fname = str(i)+'.xlsx'
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(fname)
    sh = wb.active
    vedomost.append([sh.cell(row=2,column=2).value,sh.cell(row=2,column=4).value])

vedomost = sorted(vedomost)
for i in range(len(vedomost)):
    print((' ').join(map(str,vedomost[i])), sep='\n')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]